# Partial copy of dynamic object in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

As you can see below, in the json i have "data", "data2" and invoice.
My goal is to split a json file in more parts that have "data" and "data2" and a part of "invoice". 
I've de-serialized the string, that contain the json code, in a dynamic object so i need to make a partial copy of this in a temp dynamic object, serialize it and than continue my job.

```
 string strJsonOuput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlInput);
 dynamic objComune = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strJsonOuput);
```

This an example of the json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  },
  "data2": {
    "something1": {
        "thing1": "xxx",
    },
    "Invoice": [
      {
        "head": "bbb",
        "body": {
          "argument1":"aaa"
        }
      }
      {
         "head": "xxxx",
         "body": {
         "argument2": "ccc"
            }
      }
      {
         "head": "xxxx",
         "body": {
         "argument2": "ccc"
            }
      }
      {...}
      ]
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you use `dynamic`?

Comment: Simply create two new classes, one for part1 and one for part2. Then deserialize your *entire* json into *one single* instance and write its part1-properties into a new instance of part1-class and the part2-properties into the instance of part2-class.

Comment: Can you explain me your idea with some code? I'm new with c#